# How to replace existing UIColors

Tags: subclass, uicolor, redefine

I am trying to make a theming system for my app. Is there a way to redefine the default UIColors? I already tried to subclass UIColor:

```
//.h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor(UIColor_themeColor)

+ (UIColor *)blackColor;

@end

//.m file

#import "UIColor+themeColor.h"
#import "DeviceColor.h"

@implementation UIColor(UIColor_themeColor)

+ (UIColor *)blackColor {
    return [self  blackColor];
}

@end
```

But then I get the warning `Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class` which is understandable, and the app will crash if I build it.

Is there a way do what I like to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preamble you'll get from everyone, I think: doing what you want to do is a bad idea as a method called `blackColor` should return the colour black. Methods should always be appropriately named.

Post-preamble:

Use method swizzling. You can't do it directly through declarations but because the Objective-C runtime is dynamic, you can switch the implementations of methods at runtime. You need to talk to [the runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) directly, with its C API, but it's not too tricky.

[Mike Ash's](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-29-method-replacement-for-fun-and-profit.html) guide walks you through the theory and shows you the code, much more clearly than I'm likely to here.